# FusionAuth External JWT Provider

Tags: fusionauth

I am trying to login using JWT token issued by External JWT Provider.
When I use Reconcile API I got 500 error with following stack trace:

```
Aug 20, 2019 8:03:16.428 AM ERROR io.fusionauth.app.primeframework.error.ExceptionExceptionHandler - An unhandled exception was thrown
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at io.fusionauth.jwt.domain.JWT.lookupClaim(JWT.java:416)
        at io.fusionauth.jwt.domain.JWT.getString(JWT.java:347)
        at io.fusionauth.api.service.authentication.ExternalJWTIdentityProviderAuthenticationService.reconcile(ExternalJWTIdentityProviderAuthenticationService.java:90)
        at io.fusionauth.app.action.api.identityProvider.LoginAction.post(LoginAction.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:436)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.execute(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:84)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:64)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.validation.DefaultValidationWorkflow.perform(DefaultValidationWorkflow.java:47)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSecurityWorkflow.perform(DefaultSecurityWorkflow.java:60)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.java:50)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.content.DefaultContentWorkflow.perform(DefaultContentWorkflow.java:52)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultParameterWorkflow.java:57)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.java:102)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.scope.DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.perform(DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.java:58)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.message.DefaultMessageWorkflow.perform(DefaultMessageWorkflow.java:45)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.java:126)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.StaticResourceWorkflow.perform(StaticResourceWorkflow.java:97)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.RequestBodyWorkflow.perform(RequestBodyWorkflow.java:89)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.perform(DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.java:57)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.DefaultMVCWorkflow.perform(DefaultMVCWorkflow.java:91)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.DefaultWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(DefaultWorkflowChain.java:44)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.FilterWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(FilterWorkflowChain.java:50)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.PrimeFilter.doFilter(PrimeFilter.java:84)
        at com.inversoft.maintenance.servlet.MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.doFilter(MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.inversoft.servlet.CORSFilter.handleNonCORS(CORSFilter.java:748)
        at com.inversoft.servlet.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.inversoft.servlet.UTF8Filter.doFilter(UTF8Filter.java:27)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is my decoded JWT payload:

```
{
  "user_name": "name.surname",
  "scope": [
    "read"
  ],
  "exp": 1566331043,
  "applicationId": "37cf7a75-6b3a-49d9-99d9-6f261c4f6851",
  "jti": "eddc15b6-f479-47c0-8d08-8b9aacf6dbe8",
  "email": "name.surname@domain.pl",
  "client_id": "37cf7a75-6b3a-49d9-99d9-6f261c4f6851"
}
```

“uniqueIdentityClaim” in provider config is set to “email”. I tried setting it to “user_name” too, but it does nothing.
Looks like it searches for “null” claim at io.fusionauth.jwt.domain.JWT.lookupClaim(JWT.java:416) but I have no idea when and how could it pass null there, when the token has all fields filled. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

UPDATE:
I tried to make it work and I noticed that it works in specific case. Here is part of the code:

```
        UUID appId = fusionAuthConfig.getApplication().id;
        LookupResponse lookupResponse = lambdaDelegate.execute(x -> x.lookupIdentityProvider("domain.pl"));
        IdentityProviderLoginRequest request = new IdentityProviderLoginRequest();
        request.identityProviderId = lookupResponse.identityProvider.id;
        request.applicationId = appId;
        request.setEncodedJWT(token);
        LoginResponse response = lambdaDelegate.execute(x -> x.reconcileJWT(request));
        return response;
```

When I debug on line

```
        LoginResponse response = lambdaDelegate.execute(x -> x.reconcileJWT(request));
```

and wait a while, it works. There is no error, user is registered and logged in FusionAuth in my application and I am authorized in endpoints when I use returned token.
Still trying to figure out why works when I debug on that line and wait.

Comment: That NPE looks to be using the unique claim name which is a required field, so that is strange that it appears to be looking up a null value. What version of FusionAuth are you running, in the latest released version you can enable debug in the config which will produce an event log to review.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it. Problem was in using lambdaDelegate. When I removed
'''

```
LookupResponse lookupResponse = lambdaDelegate.execute(x -> x.lookupIdentityProvider("domain.pl"));
```

''' 
it worked. I just had to pass identifyProviderUuid, not to lookup for it. Looks like there is some kind of conflict when 2 methods from FusionAuth are called one after another and the first one is not finished yet